# Sorted sheets without any sense xlsx

Tags: python, xlsx

I have an xlsx fine with three sheets and I have a code to sorted they but I want to sorted  by my way and not by name:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')

sheet_names = ['Data1', 'Chart1', 'Data2', 'Chart2', 'Data3', 'Chart3']
for sheet_name in sheet_names:
    workbook.add_worksheet(sheet_name)

# sort sheets based on name
workbook.worksheets_objs.sort(key=lambda x: x.name)
workbook.close()
```

Sheets sorted that I need:

```
sheet_names = ['Data1', 'Chart1', 'Chart3', 'Chart2', 'Data3', 'Data2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you perhaps try this?  It tries to sort on the index in the second array.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')

sheet_names = ['Data1', 'Chart1', 'Data2', 'Chart2', 'Data3', 'Chart3']
for sheet_name in sheet_names:
    workbook.add_worksheet(sheet_name)

new_sheet_names = ['Data1', 'Chart1', 'Chart3', 'Chart2', 'Data3', 'Data2']

# sort sheets based on name
workbook.worksheets_objs.sort(key=lambda x: new_sheet_names.index(x.name))
workbook.close()
```

Comment: The problem is that scrypt create new sheets and I need to change the place not create new ones!

Comment: yes...the new sheet names array is intended to have the expected sort...then...the new_sheet_names.index(x.name) sorts it based on the new sheet names array...my code doesn't add 6 new sheets